# Upload file button

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to have a simple button inside my google spreadsheet that will upload the selected file to the specific folder on Google Drive. Without applying google forms. Just one upload button. Does anyone have some script code example for this task?

Comment: Where was the selected file?

Comment: Upload from the hard drive of one who is pressing the button and runs the script I mean

Comment: Thank you for replying. You want to upload the files on your local PC to the specific folder of your Google Drive by clicking a button putting on the active Spreadsheet. And the user for this situation is you. I could understand like this from your question and reply comment. Is my understanding correct? By the way, can I ask you about ``Just one upload button``?

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want a button in your SpreadSheet to upload a file from your PC to your Google Drive. 
The first step is to create an upload script. You can use the [sample](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert#examples) from the Google Drive API documentation:

```
function insertFile(fileData, callback) {
  const boundary = '-------314159265358979323846';
  const delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
  const close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsBinaryString(fileData);
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    var contentType = fileData.type || 'application/octet-stream';
    var metadata = {
      'title': fileData.fileName,
      'mimeType': contentType
    };

    var base64Data = btoa(reader.result);
    var multipartRequestBody =
        delimiter +
        'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
        JSON.stringify(metadata) +
        delimiter +
        'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' +
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' +
        '\r\n' +
        base64Data +
        close_delim;

    var request = gapi.client.request({
        'path': 'your path file',
        'method': 'POST',
        'params': {'uploadType': 'multipart'},
        'headers': {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"'
        },
        'body': multipartRequestBody});
    if (!callback) {
      callback = function(file) {
        console.log(file)
      };   }    request.execute(callback);  }}
```

Then, you have to create the button in your Sheet. To do this go to Insert > Drawing (or image if you have one) and draw your custom button.
Once you are done, right click on the button and select “Assign script”, and write the name of your saved script.